# resultCode is always 0

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the resultCode to be OK inside my onActivityResult function. However, it keeps coming back as 0. I have spent several days on this, and can't figure out why it doesn't work. Here's my code. If anybody can help me, I'll be very grateful, Thanks.

My Activity1 class:

```
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                // process
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
            i.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityOne ");
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
            textView.setText(result);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
                       // do something
                }
        }
```

My Activity 2 class:

```
    @Override
    public void finish() {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("returnKey1", "return 1");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        super.finish();
    }
```

My manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Activity1"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2"
                  android:label="@string/app_dialog_name" 
                  android:launchMode="singleTop" 
                  android:excludeFromRecents="true"
              android:taskAffinity="" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Where and how variable RESULT_OK is declared?

Comment: @NOSTRA : RESULT_OK is a public static final constant declared in Activity.

Comment: Also, when I try debugging it, I noticed that the onActivityResult gets called right away before the MyActivity2 even starts.

Answer (score 3):

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

is the problem. According to docs:

```
This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from the activity being launched.
```

Answer (score 1):

finish() is actually not one of the callbacks you get as part of the activity lifecycle. Can you confirm that you're calling finish() yourself within MyActivity2.

If you're not calling finish() by yourself, you should call setResult(), within the the onDestroy() of MyActivity2.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Exactly, `finish` is a method for you to call. It is not a method called by Android.

Comment: Yes, this is how I call my finish:

 public void onClick(View view) {
  finish();
 }

Comment: Try setting the setResult() within onDestroy, as it is the last callback that you get when the activity is finishing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried:

 public void onDestroy(){
  setResult(RESULT_OK);
  super.onDestroy();
 }

and that still doens't work :(

Answer (score -1):

If you call finish() for your Activity it will be always 0 as result ([http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29))

There is another method exists: finishActivity(int requestCode).

But if you want put Extras in Result we need other way. So why do you override finish() method? Where from do you call this method?

Comment: When I try not to override it, it still doesn't work. I call the finish() on my onClick method. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I think this: **i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);** is your problem. Delete it and you'll be happy :) Why do you need this flag?

Comment: I need this flag because I need it to alert the user when they are in another application. thanks for your answer :). I really appreciate it.

Comment: So do you find a solution? :)

Comment: Nope. Lol. Still trying to figure it out. I'm new to android. :)